# Java includes any switch or change command for android ?

Tags: java, javascript, android

I'm trying to make a in-game shop for my Android game which is selling some extra things (health,dresses etc etc.) But i need something like, When player press button which in shop, change the X object with this button's Object. I know maybe this is complex for it but, if you can give me an advice, or code buckets, i'm so much appreciated to you. Thanks..

Comment: I don't even have a clue what you need here. Please elaborate this question. "When player press button which in shop, change the X object with this button's Object" - this is the most obscure part of it. Put it here with more words and details, make some illustrations too, because I can see from here where we're going.

Comment: Ah i'm sorry, i think i couldnt intruduce my problem. Imagine a X character which is main character and a shop which created with buttons for players extra items. For example dress, when players had enough Z collectable item from game , with this button in shop ; they can buy items. I can make all general design for shop(buttons , pictures etc.) but i need a switch for , when players press this button, it can be switch with main X character. Is that more elaborately ? Thanks for your comment..

Comment: Well, what i understood is, that you want to have a separate screen for this shop - right? What I didn't understood however is this part - "it can be switch with main X character" - what is the main "X" character going to be switched with?

Comment: Actually, you understood is wrong. Imagine a shop for normal games. You will collect collectable items from game and buy something from shop. Thats how i want to work this shop. Collect items from game, for example coins. And you will go to shop button and choose one of the Bonus Things , for example extra health , dresses. But i need firstly extra dress, or hat, scarf etc. When player click this button. This button can be work as switching image with standart image for X character. When this player buy any of this scarf, this button can change standart X character image with scarf img..

Comment: :) Now I get it. Let me ask you this - how do you draw your caracter?

Comment: I draw as sketch to A4 , and scanned to pc by my printer's scanner. And i draw again with mouse in photoshop and colored it with some shaders. It takes me 3 day :)

Comment: :-D That's a good one, but I meant how do you make your character appear on the screen of the device, while in the application of the game.

Comment: Do you mean codes ? Or classes ? If you're asking that. There's no app in coding. I just ask how can i do that . Because i know oter things which i need for know. Lets say that , searching informations. Can you help me about that ? ^^ If you want codes, i'm at  work now ; i can send you codes when i will go home. You want them as comment to there ?

Comment: I want the code of the application (only the relevant parts of it) in the question body and with the propper selection, so it's readable. Thanks

Comment: If i send the codes when i'm at home, can you look at them if there's no problem for you ?

Comment: Well, when you paste the code here (please do not paste everything), write a comment that you did and I'll look at it when i can - is that alright for you?

Comment: All right , thanks for eveything for now ^^